# How to change contents of dropdown depending on value of another dropdown in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, contact-form-7

I would like to change the contents of a dropdown menu (combobox) A with respect to the contents of a dropdown menu B. The mapping is static and will never change. Let's say that dropdown menu A contains **"fruits", "animals", "cars"** and B should contain:

```
"dog", "cat" if menu A is set to "animal"
"peach", "cherry" if menu A is set to "fruits"
"volvo", "subaru" if menu A is set to "cars"
```

I am trying to implement this through [Contact Form 7](https://contactform7.com/docs/) and the [Dynamic select for Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-select-extension/). I have installed the PHP filter that controls the contents of menu B. however, I have no idea how to pass the selected value of menu A as an argument to the filter of menu B:

[image]

It seems that what I am doing is too complicated for such an undoubtedly ubiquitous problem. If that is the case, is there a simpler way to solve this problem?